# Why is my committed memory not all being used/shown on task manager?

Tags: virtual-memory

For some reason it says I have 13.2GB of memory committed but on the memory area it only says 3.4GB.

Committed:

[image: Committed]

Real memory:

[image: Real memory.]

Comment: FWIW, the screenshot you uploaded for “Real memory:” seems to be 100% the same as the “Committed:” screenshot. If you can upload the correct screenshot someone can properly set it as an inline image.

Comment: RAMMap provides an improved and more accurate view of memory usage

Comment: Are you getting confused between virtual memory and real memory?  You can have more virtual memory committed than you have real memory.  VM resides on the disk.

Comment: @giacomo1968 Im just not that well knowledged for computer stuff so I was confused and didnt know.

Comment: @iiSilencedNeø Well, can you upload correct images?

Answer (score 0):

As for me this is totally normal behavior on Linux, it is called memory overcommit.
However, in case you are worried about the health of your system, or you feel like the performance is bad, you can check which processes consume the most virtual memory using the command below:

```
ps aux | head -1; ps aux | sort -rnk 5
```

Execute this command after some time again and compare the results. You may find several processes that consumed a significant amount of memory during this time.

Then you can check the memory layout of these processes using the *pmap* utility or the */proc* directory:

```
➜  ~ sudo cat /proc/2095/maps
c000000000-c000600000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
c000600000-c001200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
c001200000-c004000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
55ee50165000-55ee51972000 r--p 00000000 fd:01 11799696                   /usr/bin/dockerd
55ee51972000-55ee535be000 r-xp 0180d000 fd:01 11799696                   /usr/bin/dockerd
55ee535be000-55ee5392f000 r--p 03459000 fd:01 11799696                   /usr/bin/dockerd
55ee53930000-55ee54f5d000 r--p 037ca000 fd:01 11799696                   /usr/bin/dockerd
55ee54f5d000-55ee54ffd000 rw-p 04df7000 fd:01 11799696                   /usr/bin/dockerd
55ee54ffd000-55ee55045000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
55ee568ad000-55ee568ce000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
```

Save the memory layout of the target process, then check it again after some time and compare the results. If the start/end addresses of some heap or stack, or other memory regions significantly changed, you may find the memory you are looking for.

P.S. I did find the leak in my C++ APP this way: I didn't released properly the resources of the JSON library I used for parsing, so one of the memory regions was growing constantly.